# ng-click does not fire in or out of ng-table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

How do you get the ng-click event to actually fire? I've tried everything to get this to work.  I know the alert is working initially, but after the list is displayed, quite magically all the buttons fail to function.

Here is the display of the page (pre/post alert).  I've verified that each button for details is getting a unique id. As you can see, I've also tried $parent (since some of the buttons are within a ng-repeat) as well as $rootscope to try to get things to execute (i.e. the detail buttons).  It's almost as if, after the initially display, the page has lost the reference to the angularjs file since nothing functions:

[When page is first displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixdtN.png)

[After getting the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiOb9.png)

**Here's the AngularJS file:**

```
var app = angular.module("EmployeeApplication", [])
.controller("EmployeeController",
    function ($scope, $http,$window) {

        AngularInit();

        function AngularInit() {
            //This will be called once per form load, via the ng-load function on the div
            $scope.name = '';
            $scope.gender = '';
            $scope.salary = '';
            $scope.id = '';
            $scope.DisplayAction = 'Unknown';
            $scope.gotdata = false;
            DisplayList();
            ShowAlert('test')
        }

        function GetAllEmployees($http) {
            //$scope.Message = 'NULL';
            //$scope.employees = {};
            $http.get('http://localhost:65315/api/employee').then(function (response) {
                $scope.employees = response.data;
                $scope.Message = 'OK';
                $scope.gotdata = true;
            },
            function (err) {
                $scope.Message = 'Call failed' + err.status + '  ' + err.statusText;
                $scope.employees = {};
                $scope.gotdata = false;
            }
            );

            //window.setTimeout(function () {
            //    $scope.gotdata = true;
            //}, 1000);
        };

        function DisplayList() {
            //call the web service to get the list of people
            //set the display action so that the list will be displayed
            GetAllEmployees($http)
            $scope.DisplayAction = 'List';
        };

        function CreateNewEmployee() {
            $scope.name = '';
            $scope.gender = '';
            $scope.salary = '';
            $scope.id = '';
            $scope.DisplayAction = 'Create';
            $scope.$apply();
        };

        function ShowDetails(id) {
            //call the web service to get the details of the person
            ShowAlert('test')
            $scope.gotdata = false;
            $http.get('http://localhost:65315/api/employee/' + id).then(function (response) {
                $scope.employees = response.data;
                $scope.DisplayAction = 'Details';
                $scope.Message = 'OK';
            },
            function (err) {
                $scope.Message = 'Call failed' + err.status + '  ' + err.statusText;
                $scope.employees = {};
            }
            );


            //Set the $scope.CurrentEmployee
            $scope.$apply();
        };
        function ShowAlert(msg)
        {
            $window.alert(msg);
        }

        function CreateEmployee() {

            //perform the actual creation based on $scope.CurrentEmployee

            //if successful
            DisplayList();
        };

        function DeleteEmployee(id) {
            $scope.DisplayAction = 'Delete';
            $scope.$apply();
        };

        function DoDeleteEmployee(id) {
            //Perform actual deletion
            //if successful
            DisplayList();
        };

        function EditEmployee(id) {
            //get the employee based on ID
            $scope.DisplayAction = 'Edit';
            $scope.$apply();
        };

        function EditUpdate() {
            //perform the actual update based on $scope.id

            //if successful
            DisplayList();
        };
    }

);

//angular.module('EmployeeApplication', [])
//   .controller('EmployeeController', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) {
//       $scope.greeting = 'Hello, World!';
//       $scope.doGreeting = function (greeting) {
//           $window.alert(greeting);
//       };
//   }]);



var app = angular.module("MyModule", []).controller("MyController", function ($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.MadeItHereMessage = 'We made it to the controller (first controller)';
    $scope.employees = {};
    $http.get('http://localhost:65315/api/employee').then(function (response) {
        $scope.employees = response.data;
        $scope.Message = "OK";
    },
    function (err)
    {
        $scope.Message = "Call failed" + err.status + "  " + err.statusText;
    }
    );

});


//var app = angular.module("MyModule", []).controller("MyController", function initController($scope)
//{
//        $scope.MadeItHereMessage = 'This is a loadtest';
//});

//var app = angular.module("EmployeeApplication", ['$rootscope','$scope','$http'])
//.controller("EmployeeController",

//    function AppCtrl($rootscope,$scope, $http)
//    {
//        $scope.DisplayAction = "List";
//    }

//);

//var app = angular.module("MyModule", []).controller("MyController", function ($scope, $http) {
//    $http.get('EmployeeWebService.asmx/GetAllEmployees').then(function (response) {
//        $scope.employees = response.data;
//    }
//    );

//});
```

**Here is the HTML file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/EmployeeAngular.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body ng-app="EmployeeApplication">

<div ng-controller="EmployeeController" ng-init="AngularInit()">
    {{Message}}
    <br/>
        {{DisplayAction}}
    <button id="btnCreateNew1" ng-click="$parent.ShowAlert('Parent scope button pressed')">Show message from parent scope</button>
    <br />
        <!--The following is for listing the entire list of employees-->
        <div id="listSection" ng-show="DisplayAction=='List'">
            <!--The employees data is: {{employees}}-->
    <!--<div id="listSection">-->
        <table>
            <thead>List of defined Employees</thead>
            <tr>
                <!--<td><button id="btnCreateNew" ng-click="CreateNewEmployee()">Create Employee</button></td>-->
                <td><button id="btnCreateNew" ng-click="$rootscope.ShowAlert('Create button pressed')">Create Employee</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td ng-show="gotdata">

                    <table id="EmployeeList">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Gender</th>
                                <th>Salary</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees" ng-if="employees && employees!={undefined}">
                                <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
                                <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
                                <td>{{employee.gender}}</td>
                                <td>{{employee.salary}}</td>

                                <td><button id="btnDetailsA{{employee.id}}" ng-click="$parent.ShowDetails({{employee.id}})">Details</button></td>
                                <td><button id="btnDetailsB{{employee.id}}" ng-click="$parent.ShowDetails({{employee.id}})">Details B</button></td>
                                <td><button id="btnDetailsC{{employee.id}}" ng-click="ShowDetails({{employee.id}})">Details C</button></td>
                                <td><button id="btnDetailsD{{employee.id}}" ng-click="$scope.ShowDetails({{employee.id}})">Details D</button></td>
                                <td><button id="btnDetailsE{{employee.id}}" ng-click="$rootscope.ShowDetails({{employee.id}})">Details E</button></td>

                                <td><button id="btnDelete{{employee.id}}" ng-click="$parent.DeleteEmployee({{employee.id}})">Delete</button></td>
                                <td><button id="btnEdit{{employee.id}}"  ng-click="$parent.EditEmployee({{employee.id}})">Edit</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
        <!--The following is for listing the details of a single employee-->
        <div id="DetailsSection" ng-show="DisplayAction=='Details'">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID:</td>
                    <td> <input id="DetailsID" value={{employee.id}} /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td><input id="DetailsName" value={{employee.name}} /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gender:</td>
                    <td><input id="DetailsGender" value={{employee.gender}} /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Salary:</td>
                    <td><input id="DetailsSalary" value={{employee.salary}} /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button id="NavTolist" ng-click="DisplayList()">Back to List</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="NavToDelete" ng-click="DeleteEmployee({{id}})">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="NavToEdit" ng-click="EditEmployee({{id}})">Edit</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!--The following is for editing a employee-->
        <!--<div id="EditSection" ng-show="DisplayAction=='Edit'">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="ID" value={{id}} />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td><input id="" value={{name}} ng-bind="name" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gender:</td>
                    <td><input id="" value={{gender}} ng-bind="gender" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Salary:</td>
                    <td><input id="" value={{salary}} ng-bind="salary" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button id="EditUpdate" type="button" value="Update" ng-click="EditUpdate()"></button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="NavTolistEdit" type="button" value="Back to List" ng-click="DisplayList()"></button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="NavToDeleteEdit" type="button" value="Delete" ng-click="DeleteEmployee({{id}})"></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>-->
        <!--The following is for verification of deletion-->
        <div id="DeletionSection" ng-show="DisplayAction=='Delete'">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Do you really want to delete {{name}}</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="btnCancelDelete" type="button" value="No" ng-click="DisplayList()"></button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="btnDeleteEmployee" type="button" value="Yes" ng-click="DoDeleteEmployee({{id}})"></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!--The following is for creation of a employee-->
        <!--<div id="CreationSection" ng-show="DisplayAction=='Create'">

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td><input id="" value="" ng-bind="name" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gender:</td>
                    <td><input id="" value="" ng-bind="gender" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Salary:</td>
                    <td><input id="" value="" ng-bind="salary" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button id="btnCreateEmployee" type="button" value="Delete" ng-click="CreateEmployee()"></button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="NavTolistEdit" type="button" value="Back to List" ng-click="DisplayList()"></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why do you keep javascript functions? you should be having either controller as (`this.`) or scope functions (`$scope.`). Also, can you make a fiddle or plnkr to play around with?

Answer (score 0):

unlike vanilla event handlers, ng-click will look for a event handler in the controller scope, so when you have:

```
<button id="NavTolist" ng-click="DisplayList()">Back to List</button>
```

your controller must have:

```
$scope.DisplayList = function() {
  //call the web service to get the list of people
  //set the display action so that the list will be displayed
  GetAllEmployees($http)
  $scope.DisplayAction = 'List';
};
```

you might be interested in take a look in a few [sample](https://github.com/sombriks/blogpost-upload-angular-browserify-fngfileupload) projects over the web in order to better organize your code.

on a side note, whenever possible sample your web-capable code on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/) / [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) / [codepen](http://codepen.io/), since it provides a huge help for anyone willing to help.